# How to fix Visual Studio dll symbol locations?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, pdb-files

I have a VLD dependency in a C++ project where previously everything worked fine in regard to debugging. However, I connected to my school's network drive (Z:) and opened visual studio from there; this presented me with a prompt that mentioned changing temporary symbol locations, which I approved. This was a couple of weeks ago, and now I've realized that the effect of this was to add 2 minutes prior to app startup (when debugging) trying to load the VLD .dll symbols from the directory on the Z: drive the project was in. (despite executing in the C: drive location)

Attempting to fix it, I've tried:

- Reinstalling VLD
- Cleaning the solution
- Deleting the .VC.db

None of these work, and the only symbol related settings I've found (under Tools-Options-Debugging-Symbols) seem to be irrelevant. What do I have to do to fix this issue? I'm using VS 2015.

Comment: I personnally use the `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH` en variable (set to `srv*C:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/downloads/symbols`), it works for all tools (VS, WinDbg, etc.)

Comment: @SimonMourier Do you know if there's an equivalent if it's not using the microsoft symbol server?

Comment: Oh you mean you don't want to download symbols at all? Sorry I didn't understand that